# Word boundary regexp in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's suppose I have the following string:

```
bla bla "some" bla bla some bla bla something
```

I would like to replace all occurences of 'some' bounded non-word symbols with ''. I wrote a regular expression for this purpose:

```
/^|[^0-9a-zа-я](some)[^0-9a-zа-я]|$/gi
```

How I use it:

```
'bla bla "some" bla bla some bla bla something'.replace(/^|[^0-9a-zа-я](some)[^0-9a-zа-я]|$/gi, '<$1>')
```

And its result is

```
<>bla bla <some> bla bla<some>bla bla something<>
```

But I expected

```
bla bla "<some>" bla bla <some> bla bla something
```

How could I fix this regex? As I know JavaScript's regular expressions don't support named groups.

Note: I can not use `\b` because words I want to match contain cyrillic symbols and `\b` in Javascript's regex engine doesn't work properly with non-latin letters.

Comment: The `а-я` range only includes [basic Cyrillic letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode#Basic_Cyrillic_alphabet) and does not include any [extended ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode#Cyrillic_extensions) (for instance `ё` for Russian or `[ґєії]` for Ukrainian). You probably want to include these extended letters too. What language you're going to process?

Comment: Let's ask straight: Do you need to support any Unicode letters? If yes, you need an XRegExp based solution, and I already answered such a question. Else, use the custom word boundary for a specified Unicode letter range, but please clarify the requirements.

Comment: @DmitryEgorov I want to process russian language

Comment: Then just add `ё` to the character ranges. Please see the updated answer of mine.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something along those lines :

```
yourString.replace(/(^|[^0-9a-zа-я])(some)(?![0-9a-zа-я])/gi, '$1<$2>')
```

[Try it online.](https://regex101.com/r/cuDYh5/2)

Note that as [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970) comments on another answer, your character class only matches the [basic Cyrillic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode#Basic_Cyrillic_alphabet) and would miss other Cyrillic characters. An alternative would be to stop using a negated character class and instead match characters you expect as word separators if they are easier to enumerate. In that optic `["\s]` would appear to be a good start :

```
yourString.replace(/(^|[\s"])(some)(?![^\s"])/gi, '$1<$2>')
```

[Try it online.](https://regex101.com/r/VUy5Bv/1)

Answer (score 1):

Group and capture the opening and closing alternatives and include these captures in the replacement string too:

```js
var regex = /(^|[^0-9a-zа-яё])(some)([^0-9a-zа-яё]|$)/gi;
var output = 'bla bla "some" bla bla some bla bla something'.replace(regex, '$1<$2>$3');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: You forgot about `ё`. There are other Cyrillic letters other than `а-я`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: yes, you're right. I just copied the range from the OP. What letters out of the basic Cyrillic Unicode table to be included depends on the language. This depends on the language being processed and requires clarification.